# British terminology in "Away from it All"

Tags: monty-python

In the narration of Monty Python's short, [*Away from it All*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFWo1oqZTe4), there is some British terminology and accents that I can't understand. I have marked the parts I can't understand as question marks:

[quoted material begins at 11:45]

> Because they don't have to pay a proper aisle/hire (???) charge for films
>   like this. That's why! They're dead cheap. Well, I don't care about
>   you lot and I can't take it anymore. I can't stand any more of these
>   films. They make me throw up. No, I've got to get away. Get right
>   away. Fly off to some sun-drenched, polyglot (???), ??? paradise jam
>   packed with wild-eyed, snake-hipped, tony Danish blondes where the
>   fountains spout glittering cascades of ???.

Can anyone tell me what the narrator is saying at the points in question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After finding some subtitles online that were somewhat correct and listening to it a few times I believe this is what is being said.

> Because they don't have to pay a proper hire charge for films like this, that's why. They're dead cheap.

A hire charge would be the rental fee that is paid to show the movie. Travelogue movies charge cheaper fees.

> Fly off to some sun-drenched, polyglot pagan paradise jam packed with wild eyed snake hipped horny Danish blondes.

A location that is multilingual with people who have little religion and revel in sensual pleasures. Preferably peopled with blonde women from Denmark that are eager for sex and willing to do a lot of the work.

> And where the fountains spout glittery cascades of Vino rosso till eternity.

Where the fountains flow with red wine so we can be drunk for all eternity.

Comment: Good job, could you do this with the entire script of Lock Stock and Two Smoking Barrels?